# XSLT Template Table

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am trying to get some data in the form of a Table but it does not seem possible to do so.
I would like the data to appear in a normal table like form like it usually does with the html table tags. It always comes out vertically instead of a normal horizontal table.
Is it possible? Am I missing something here?
So far this is my code and what the result looks like underneath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <tr>
      <span style="background-color: #aaa;">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> : 
      </span>
      <span style="background-color: #ccc;">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </span>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <tr>
      <th style="border:2px solid #c55; font-size:120%;">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqJTg.png)

Comment: a `tr` should consist of `td`'s. Not `span`

Comment: I  have tried that but it does not make a difference. I have spans cause they take less space inbetween rows at least to not have too much empty space vertically.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere here where you are generating a table row (`tr`) that contains more than one cell (`td`). So it's fairly evident that this code will generate a single-column table.

It's easier to see what's wrong than to tell how to fix it, because I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve: you haven't described your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply. Turns out I needed something like in the code below. You are right however, I was missing something.

```
xsl:template match="/">
    <style>
      body {font-family: sans-serif;}

      td {padding: 4px;}
    </style>
    <table style="position: absolute; top: 70px;">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #aaa;">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></p>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color: #ccc;">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
      <th style="border:2px solid #c55; font-size:120%;">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </th>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
```